# How to prevent user manually to dashboard without login with redux

Tags: reactjs

i have a problem that still not solve, how to prevent user manually type the path to dashboard before login, i already create global state and dispatch to dashboard with this.props.handlelogin . and to path addadmin, so i need to solve when people goo to path addadmin or dashboard before login it will return false and required login.

index.js

```
const globalState = {
    isLogedIn : false,
    password : '',
    email : ''

}

const rootReducer = (state = globalState ,action) => {
  if (action.type === 'AUTH') {
      return  {
          ...state,
          email : state.email,
          password : state.password,
          isLogedIn : true
      }
  }

  if (action.type === 'AUTH_LOGIN') {
      return {
        ...state,
        isLogedIn : true 
      }
  }

  return state;
}


const storeRedux = createStore(rootReducer);
const customHistory = createHashHistory();


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {storeRedux}>
      <Router history={customHistory}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin" render={props => <AdminLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/auth" render={props => <AuthLayout {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/" render= {() => <LandingLogin/>} />
          <Route exact path="/login" render= {() => <LandingLogin/>} />
          <Route exact path="/register" render= {() => <LandingRegister/>} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

admin.js

```
componentWillMount() {
        if(!this.props.handleLogin){
            alert('Require Login User :)')
            customHistory.push('/');    
        }
  }
const mapStatetoProps =(state) => {
  return {
    isLogedIn : state.isLogedIn
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      handleLogin :  () => dispatch({type : 'AUTH'}),
      handleLog : () => dispatch({type :'AUTH_LOGIN'})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, In you index.js you can define a function that would return a Boolean value checking if user is authenticated or not 
like **`isAuthenticated()`** , so when ever the user manually enter the url and if the user is not authenticated it will redirect to login.

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard" 
  render={props => 
  isAuthenticated()?(<DashboardContainer {...props} />):(<Redirect to="/login" />) }/>
```